# SonarLint Connected mode for multiple projects

Tags: c#, sonarlint

So,
The company has a SonarQube key for each individual project.  So, we got a Common.dll project, and a Network.dll project, and a MyProject.exe project all maintained in SonarQube as individual projects.
However, in my Visual Studio i have one solution with all three projects.  How can I "bind" each project to SonarQube for all of them, so that the binding is between Common.dll and Common.dll, not MyProject.Exe for all three.

(if that makes sense).  I want the connected mode binding to be individual to project, not one project for the entire solution.

Thanks
Jaeden "Sifo Dyas" al'Raec Ruiner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by SonarLint and there is no plan for short-term on this.

Comment: two and a half years after this, has this changed? I am in the same situation, but with python: one multi-folder workspace with 3 different projects. Can i bind each one to its own project in sonarqube? Is there a plan to change `sonarlint.connectedMode.project` to be a list of `serverId`, `projectFolder` and `projectKey` for example?

Comment: It is still not supported...

Answer (score 0):

You may exclude common projects from analysis. A `PropertyGroup` that I shared below, conditionally excludes the library from the analysis scope based on a solution's name (.NET csproj file):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SonarQubeExclude Condition=" $(SolutionName) == 'Solution1' ">true</SonarQubeExclude>
  </PropertyGroup>
```